# Premiere pro audio amplify not showing up in waveform?

Tags: video-editing, adobe-premiere

I recorded my audio clips separate to my video and now all of then need a 12 dB boost. So what I did was rather than setting the gain to each clip as I drag I added the gain to the audio track, by going into audio workspace> audio mixer> amplify as shown below.

[image]

The issue that I have his that the audio waveform does not show any change. As shown below.

[image: ere]

As I may have other broll clips that are loud then this would mess up my audio. Is there any way I can make the changes in audio level add to the entier track show up on the waveform?

Answer (score 1):

[This uservoice thread](https://adobe-video.uservoice.com/forums/911233-premiere-pro/suggestions/35783419-premiere-pro-2019-audio-gain-adjustments-either-do) suggests that this problem occurs if your clips are on an external drive. Try moving your clips onto the hard drive. (or SSD if that is what your computer is using.)

There seems to be a grey horizontal line in your waveform picture. What is that for? Perhaps it is preventing the change from taking place?

Finally, Audacity may help, and seeing as you have multiple clips, [batch processing](https://ttmanual.audacityteam.org/o/man/batch_processing.html) could speed things up.

Maybe After Effects or Vegas Pro would treat you better if you still cannot find a solution. I use Vegas and I insert an audio track that is only for temperamental clips, and it lets me alter the volume/gain for the whole track.

I hope you find what you're looking for. :)

Comment: If I change the gain of the clips individually then the waveform changes. I want the same at track level. So if I amplify a track then all the waveforms in it show reflect it visually the same way it does with individual gain change.

Comment: @krv sounds like it is working as intended! if you don't hear a difference, there might be a plugin that restrains the whole project from going above a certain number of decibels, like vegas' Wave Hammer Surround plugin.